# Uploading data on google drive with R?

Tags: r, upload, google-docs

I'm beginner on R. I'm trying to upload a data.frame into a specific folder on Google Drive using the package RGoogleDocs but I've some problems:

```
uploadDoc(f, con, FileName, binary = FALSE,open = "w+b", folder=I("drive$folders@mcmd_execenroll") 
# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
#   Could not resolve host: mcmd_execenroll
# In addition: Warning message:
# In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
#   Unrecognized CURL options: open
```

I'm a real beginner and English is my 3rd language. I really need concrete examples to understand because I find that the documents on the web very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an other method using google drive sync api on linux
there we can specify the "Path" and sychronize the files and folders with an automation through crontab with a bash script.